# Graph Analysis (using C++)

Tags: c++, data-visualization, graphs, data-analysis

I have the motion data of a moving object (X/Y position) dependent on the time.

Example data is visualized in this diagram: 
[image]

For analysis I need features like:

- vertex-density
- slope
- linear regression

Which is the best C++ library to handle with this problem?